# How do I GET an Amazon S3 presigned url's object from jQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can find nothing on Google.

I am properly creating presigned urls because they do work if I use a browser to load the request.

However, when using the identical url from a jQuery ajax call it is failing and telling me the request signature is wrong.

PS: Here are the headers. First section is from successful browser call and second section my ajax failure.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: clb7J//+XLYa+XS4HJthLdDO0KxBJU02fyBt29Kr8A2TXRJXM189tGgy7bWgmoYkDzXWUhg3R5g=
x-amz-request-id: F3A8C4ED98E5443E
Date: Mon, 04 May 2015 21:53:24 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <any valid value>
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, DELETE, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Content-Length: 0
Server: AmazonS3


BAD AJAX:

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <any valid value>
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, DELETE, HEAD
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-request-id: 05071412E03C4541
x-amz-id-2: xw5uMr2N/alPOR7MFMbX6fVkVEf1p30VhQKyP3yUqxYXxDq+vb5hzlsyShHwY4XhgAfLd3BCjG0=
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 04 May 2015 21:53:24 GMT
Server: AmazonS3


Here is my Ajax call:

    $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: presignedurl,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                dataType: "text",
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    CentralScrutinizer("FetchDetails Exception: " + error);
                },
                success: function (payload) {
                    try {
                        $('#newTaskDetails').val(payload);

                    } catch (e) {

                    }

                }
            });

The specific error is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>

Again, the closest I could find was a similar SO post for a put but they merely suggested adding the following headers:

//headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },

I tried that but it made no difference.

I also used fiddler to compare the two GETs (browser versus ajax) and the only thing different I see is the jsonp callback parameter.

That shouldn't affect the signature, should it?

Here are the headers

Browser Success:

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    x-amz-id-2: clb7J//+XLYa+XS4HJthLdDO0KxBJU02fyBt29Kr8A2TXRJXM189tGgy7bWgmoYkDzXWUhg3R5g=
    x-amz-request-id: F3A8C4ED98E5443E
    Date: Mon, 04 May 2015 21:53:24 GMT
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <any valid origin>
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, DELETE, HEAD
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
    Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
    Content-Length: 0
    Server: AmazonS3

BAD AJAX:

    HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:: <any valid origin>
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, DELETE, HEAD
    Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
    x-amz-request-id: 05071412E03C4541
    x-amz-id-2: xw5uMr2N/alPOR7MFMbX6fVkVEf1p30VhQKyP3yUqxYXxDq+vb5hzlsyShHwY4XhgAfLd3BCjG0=
    Content-Type: application/xml
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Mon, 04 May 2015 21:53:24 GMT
    Server: AmazonS3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

I removed the following from the Ajax request:

contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

And it worked just fine.

I figured this out by comparing the response headers and subtracting what was common between the two.

Once I got the similarities out the only differences were content-length and content-type.

So as an experiment I simply commented out the contentType attribute and it worked.

That does not happen too often with s3 signatures and ajax. I feel I got lucky and hope this helps someone.

Comment: Kudos on the troubleshooting job.  `Content-Type` is arguably invalid or at least meaningless on a `GET` request where there is no request body (which is the "content," the "type" of which, the header specifies on a request; it's not the type you'll accept).  The signature algorithms require it to be used in the signing process when present, though, and hence (presumably) the error.